# Approximation error upper bound for variable derived through geometric mean

Tags: approximation, upper-lower-bounds, geometric-series

This question regards discovering an **upper bound** to the **error** in an approximation derived **using the geometric mean**.

I have two sequences of *latent* variables:

$$ r_1, r_2, ..., r_n$$
$$ s_1, s_2, ..., s_n$$

These latent variables combine to produce the *observed* variables, $R$ and $S$ (where $k$ is a scalar):

$$ R = (1+kr_1)(1+kr_2)..(1+kr_n)$$
$$ S = (1+ks_1)(1+ks_2)..(1+ks_n)$$

The **true** quantity, which is not observable, that I am interested in knowing is:

$$ T = (1+k(r_1+s_1))(1+k(r_2+s_2))..(1+k(r_n+s_n)) $$

In order to approximate $T$, I derive a geometric mean of the $r_i$ and $s_i$ by:

$$ (1+kr)^n = R \implies r = \frac{R^{1/n}-1}{k} $$
$$ (1+ks)^n = S \implies s = \frac{R^{1/n}-1}{k} $$

My approximation for $T$, $\bar{T}$, is:

$$ \bar{T} = (1+k(r+s))^n = (R^{1/n} + S^{1/n} - 1)^n$$

I would like to **derive an upper bound**, $U_b$ for the error, so that:

$$ | T - \bar{T} | \leq U_b $$

What can be said about $U_b$?